# Cas and Spring example: I don't understand "setUserDetailsService"

Tags: spring, lambda, spring-security, cas

In this example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso

there is this piece of code:

```
@Bean
public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider() {

    CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
    provider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties());
    provider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator());
    provider.setUserDetailsService(
      s -> new User("casuser", "Mellon", true, true, true, true,
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN")));
    provider.setKey("CAS_PROVIDER_LOCALHOST_9000");
    return provider;
}
```

I don't understand this part:

```
provider.setUserDetailsService(
      s -> new User("casuser", "Mellon", true, true, true, true,
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN")));
```

1. what are we supposed to put here ? Am I supposed to create my own UserDetailsService (if yes, how ?) ? I was expected some 'default cas user detail service'...
2. how does this code work? creating a user to provide a UserDetailsService ?

Comment: That is just an example of simple implementation of UserDetailService using lambda (since it is a single method interface). See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html. This example will always return Mellon user on each loadUserByUsername method call. You can have your own implementation of that interface to load user from some datastore.

Comment: ok. So I need to make my own for CAS ? Still don't know how, cas user is returned by cas server, so why do I need a UserDetailService ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how Spring security works on high level.

User tries to authenticate via some type of UI (part of CAS for example). The UI will pass username/password to Spring. Spring will eventually call `UserDetailService.loadUserByUsername` and pass the username to it, and if user exists the `UserDetailService` will return non null `UserDetails`. In case of null `UserDetails` or non null one with different password Spring will fail authentication.

CAS is just an authentication server, it leaves open how user is stored. You can choose to use LDAP or database. That choice is based on different implementation of `UserDetailService`. Look at [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) again. It has list of default implementations you can use.

See part 5 of your linked tutorial. It shows how you can change both CAS and Spring Boot app to use database as user storage. The key here is that in order for back end to work with CAS server against users stored in database both need to be configured appropriately in order to look up user against database. CAS is configured via `application.properties` and Spring boot via `UserDetailService`.

Now to your questions in the comment:

> why should the client bother about how cas server store the users ?

Client should not bother with `UserDetailService`. It is only used by back end service that is secured by CAS.

> Just to be sure that I get it tight: if I just need to know 'is that
>   user connected?' then CAS is enough and I will never use
>   UserDetailService. But if I need some information about the user
>   (name, telephone etc..) then I call the UserDetailService to load it
>   (from db, ldap or whatever).

Yes and no. You dont need to store password in `UserDetails` but you need to be able to return `UserDetails` for successful CAS authenticated user. See this part from your linked tutorial:

> Note again that the principal in the database that the server uses
>   must be the same as that of the client applications.

Comment: Just to be sure that I get it tight: if I just need to know 'is that user connected?' then CAS is enough and I will never use UserDetailService. But if I need some information about the user (name, telephone etc..) then I call the UserDetailService to load it (from db, ldap or whatever).

Comment: Another question, why should the client bother about how cas server store the users ? In my app, I don"t mind that, I just want to "log in" and "log out". When I look at this worflow of cas: https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.1.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html I never need to access the database of the users.